# python -mysql fetching column values as dict instead of arrays

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to find a way to retrieve column values of a sql query result by column names instead of column index.Is there a way to achieve this using mysql.connector.

I tried below code but its not working:
    db_config = read_db_config()
    try:
     print('Connecting to MySQL database...')
     dbconnect = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
     cursor = dbconnect.cursor(dictionary=True)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of something else, but the MySQL documentation link above looks really on point for your question.